# Ejecutar una funcion tras otra con setInterval()

Tags: javascript

```js
var div500 = document.querySelector("#sec120");
        var div501 = document.querySelector("#sec121");
        var div502 = document.querySelector("#sec122");

        function op100() {
            if (div500.style.display == "block") {
                div500.style.display="none";
                div501.style.display="none";
                div502.style.display="none";
            } else {
                div500.style.display="block";
                div501.style.display="none";
                div502.style.display="none";
            }
        }

        function op101() {
            if (div501.style.display == "block") {
                div500.style.display="none";
                div501.style.display="none";
                div502.style.display="none";
            } else {
                div500.style.display="none";
                div501.style.display="block";
                div502.style.display="none";
            }
        }

        function op102() {
            if (div502.style.display == "block") {
                div500.style.display="none";
                div501.style.display="none";
                div502.style.display="none";
            } else {
                div500.style.display="none";
                div501.style.display="none";
                div502.style.display="block";
            }
        }

        function op200() {

            var opfx20 = []
            opfx20[0] = op100();
            opfx20[1] = op101();
            opfx20[2] = op102();
            
        var opn30 = 0; 

            if (opn30 < opfx20.length - 1) {
                opn30++;
            } else {
                opn30 = 0;
            } 

        }

        setInterval(op200, 1500);
```

```css
<style type="text/css">

        #bd300 {margin:0px;}

        #sec120, #sec121, #sec122 {text-align: center;
            padding: 80px 20px 80px 20px;
            margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
            background: #ccc;
            display: none;} 

        #sec300 {position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        padding: 50vh 0vh 0vh 0vh;
        text-align: center;
         }

    </style>
```

```html
<section id="sec120">
        <div id="div220">
            <p> Section 1</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section id="sec121">
        <div id="div221">
            <p> Section 2</p>
        </div>
    </section>
            
    <section id="sec122">
        <div id="div222">
            <p> Section 3</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="sec300">
        <button onclick="op100();"> Section 1 </button>
        <button onclick="op101();"> Section 2 </button>
        <button onclick="op102();"> Section 3 </button>
        <button onclick="op200();"> Section all </button>
    </section>
```

Hermanos... holas a todos!. Una pregunta... estoy practicando e intentando hacer un slider... y tengo esto que ven...

lo que intento es que el setInterval ejecute las funciones op100, op101, op102 una detras de la otra, y el resultado es que se ejecuta al instante la funcion op102 sin pasar por las otras 2 primeras... saben como hacer eso...?

la funcion del interval es op200().

que debo de corregir para que se ejecute

op100() --> finaliza y comienza --> op101() --> finaliza y comienza --> op102().

???

Gracais de antemano.! bn dia.!

Comment: Declara la variable opn30 afuera de la función op200 asi como su inicializacion.

Comment: lo hice, y no hace nada... no ejecuta ninguna de las funciones..               var opfx20 = []
            opfx20[0] = op100();
            opfx20[1] = op101();
            opfx20[2] = op102();
            
        var opn30 = 0;

        function op200() { 

            if (opn30 < opfx20.length - 1) {
                opn30++;
            } else {
                opn30 = 0;
            } 

        }

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, yo use **[setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)**, que recibe como parametro una función `function (){showPanel(div500)}` y un tiempo en milisegundos.

Te dejo tu código, un tanto editado.

```js
var div500 = document.querySelector("#sec120");
var div501 = document.querySelector("#sec121");
var div502 = document.querySelector("#sec122");

function showPanel(panel) {
  div500.style.display = "none";
  div501.style.display = "none";
  div502.style.display = "none";
  panel.style.display = "block";
}

function op200() {
  setTimeout(function (){showPanel(div500)}, 1500);
  setTimeout(function (){showPanel(div501)}, 3000);
  setTimeout(function (){showPanel(div502)}, 4500);
}

setInterval(function(){op200()},4501);
```

```css
#bd300 {
    margin: 0px;
  }

  #sec120,
  #sec121,
  #sec122 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 80px 20px 80px 20px;
    margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: none;
  }

  #sec300 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 50vh 0vh 0vh 0vh;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<section id="sec120">
  <div id="div220">
    <p> Section 1</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="sec121">
  <div id="div221">
    <p> Section 2</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="sec122">
  <div id="div222">
    <p> Section 3</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="sec300">
  <button onclick="showPanel(document.querySelector('#sec120'))"> Section 1 </button>
  <button onclick="showPanel(document.querySelector('#sec121'))"> Section 2 </button>
  <button onclick="showPanel(document.querySelector('#sec122'))"> Section 3 </button>
  <button onclick="op200()"> Section all </button>
</section>
```

Para que quede en bucle se le agrega un `setInterval`.

```
setInterval(function(){op200()},4501);
```

---

*Por otro lado, tu código es poco eficiente. Hay muchas lineas repetidas. Yo le cambie solo un poquito, pero hay muchas q ver. Ademas como recomendación personal, usa nombres representativos para las variables y las funciones. Es mas facil para otro q leen tu código, y para ti mismo, darse cuenta que cosa es cada una.*

Comment: gracicas hermano..! gracias por lo de la eficiencia... sigo trabajando en ello... ahora... lo que no veo es que se repita... si hace la funcion, pero no es un bucle infinito... como seria en ese caso?

Comment: pd: lo simplificaste bastante...! algo nuevo que aprender.! gracias.!

Comment: Lo que querias es que quede en bucle. Mala mia, en un rato edito. Entendi que querias solo ejecutar una tras otra y nada mas.

Comment: XD!! gracias hermano.! me pondre a estudiarlo.!

Comment: pd: hermano... una vez mas, te quedo buenisimo.!

Comment: Puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta si contesto a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Declara tus funciones `op100, op101 y op102` como:

```
var op100 = function {
    if (div500.style.display == "block") {
        div500.style.display="none";
        div501.style.display="none";
        div502.style.display="none";
    } else {
        div500.style.display="block";
        div501.style.display="none";
        div502.style.display="none";
    }
}

var op102 = function() {
    if (div502.style.display == "block") {
        div500.style.display="none";
        div501.style.display="none";
        div502.style.display="none";
    } else {
        div500.style.display="none";
        div501.style.display="none";
        div502.style.display="block";
    }
}

var op102 = function() {
    if (div502.style.display == "block") {
        div500.style.display="none";
        div501.style.display="none";
        div502.style.display="none";
    } else {
        div500.style.display="none";
        div501.style.display="none";
        div502.style.display="block";
    }
}
```

Y declara fuera de todas las funciones lo siguiente:

```
var opn30 = 0; 
var opfx20 = [];
opfx20.push(op100);
opfx20.push(op101);
opfx20.push(op102);
```

Y tu función `op200` quedaría:

```
function op200() {      
    if (opn30 < opfx20.length - 1) {
        opn30++;
    } else {
        opn30 = 0;
    } 
    opfx20[opn30]();
}
```

La llamada a setInterval, los javascript restantes y el html se mantiene. Espero que te funcione